# How can i get my slideshow to stop changing size?

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get my html/css slideshow to stoping changing size. I dont know how else to explain it better then "changing size" so go check it out for yourself:(To get the slideshow to load scroll down on the page then back up) [dogmother.ca](http://www.dogmother.ca). I have tried to change some of the CSS to stop it but i cant get it to work same with the html. If anyone has any ideas please tell me as I need to get this fixed as soon as possible.

The index.html  slideshow source code:

```
 <div class="slider">
        <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                <img src="images/banner1.jpg"  />
                <img src="images/banner2.jpg" />
                <img src="images/banner3.jpg"  />
                <img src="images/banner4.jpg" />
                <img src="images/banner5.jpg"  />
            </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

The css for the slide show can be found here:

http://dogmother.ca/css/slider.css

Comment: Have you tried setting a max-width/height and min-width/height?

Comment: thats not the issue id ont think did you cehck it out?

Comment: Looks like your issue is corrected on the website? I am watching your slideshow and I can't see an issue. Please advise I am missing something?

Comment: @BrianGerhards lol same I used 30 seconds to look at it and I don't see a problem...

Comment: you see how it is lower from the menu bar i want it right under the menu no space

Comment: You have hard-coded height and width for those images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your comments, it sounds like you want to remove the spacing between the navigation and your images. You have styling on the slider. Remove the top margin or change it to the value of your choosing (found in slide.css on your website)

```
}
.css-slideshow{
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1586px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto .5em auto;
}
```